# Propositional Equivalence Proof $\neg t \to u$

Tags: logic

I don't know if I can ask this here, I haven't been able to solve these logical sequences

$$\neg s\to q$$
$$(u \vee p)\to (u \vee t)$$
$$(r\land s)\to t$$
$$\neg r\to q$$
$$q\to u$$
implies that
$$\neg t \to u$$

I have tried to apply the logical laws but it did not come up with anything.\

would appreciate any hint

Answer (score 1):

First suppose $\neg t$. With the third line,we have $\neg r$ or $\neg s$. With the first and the forth lines, we have $q$. Therefore, by the last line, we have $u$. Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so here it goes a possible solution together with the reasoning behind each step.

You want to deduce $\neg t \rightarrow u$ from the given data, so the first thing to look at is a place where $\neg t$ appears; unfortunately, this doesn't happen. However, you are given that $(r\land s)\to t$ and by taking the contrapositive you know that this is logically equivalent to $\neg t \to \neg(r\land s)$. The right hand side of the latter implication is in turn logically equivalent to $\neg r \vee \neg s$, so from $(r\land s)\to t$  we have that $\neg t \to (\neg r \vee \neg s)$; note that this already looks similar to the implication we want to end up with!

Now we have $\neg r$ and $\neg s$ being introduced in the above implication; from the given information, we know that $\neg r \to u$ and $\neg s \to u$, so that $(\neg r \vee \neg s) \to u$. Combining with the above, we have that $$\neg t \to (\neg r \vee \neg s) \ \ \text{and} \ \ (\neg r \vee \neg s) \to u,$$ so by transitivity of $\to$ it follows that $\neg t \to u$, as required.